# Can I create a buffer file with arecord?

Tags: linux, debian, audio

I need to record some sounds from my audiocard to make a stream(Nothing special in this just trying new things), but I can't make the arecord play direct on it, so can I create a buffer file where the arecord saves it but didn't get bigger with time?

It will be a file where make a 10 seconds buffer and the files after 10 seconds erases it to didn't consume space on the HDD.